# Retrotif2 + RxJava sending POST request failed

Tags: http-post, retrofit2, rx-java2

I want to send POST request with Retrofit + RxJava, but it is failing and I don't know the reason. In one activity it's working, in another - don't want to work:

```
private void sendMerchantInfo() {
        try {
            String advertiserOriginalDeepLink = "https://mywebsite.com/main-1?param1=value1&param2=value2";
                String urlGetParams = LinkParser.getUrlGETParams(advertiserOriginalDeepLink);

                Map<Object, Object> merchantInfo = LinkParser.parseUrlGetParams(urlGetParams);
                String merchantInfoJson = new Gson().toJson(merchantInfo); //{"param1":"value1","param2":"value2"}

                String url = "https://api.endpoint.com/v1/system/merchant/process";
                userService = this.serviceGenerator.createService(UserService.class, true);
                final Observable observable = userService.sendUserInfo(
                        url, new RetrofitMapBody(merchantInfo))
                        .doOnNext(new Consumer<ResponseBody>() {
                            @Override
                            public void accept(ResponseBody responseBody) throws Exception {
                                //handle 200 OK.
                            }
                        })
                        .onErrorResumeNext((ObservableSource<? extends ResponseBody>) v ->
                                Crashlytics.log("Send user info attempt failed."))
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(threadExecutor))
                        .observeOn(postExecutionThread.getScheduler());
                addDisposable(observable.subscribe());
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            Crashlytics.log("Send user info attempt failed. " + exception.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I suspect that problem in this part, I am trying to send request in `OnCreate()` method:

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(threadExecutor))
.observeOn(postExecutionThread.getScheduler());
```

Tried to use this, but no effect:

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

What I am doing wrong? It always call `onErrorResumeNext()` It's probably something with threads because one time I got exception: `networkonmainthreadexception`. Please help.

Comment: why are you chaining `onErrorResumeNext`? What are you trying to accomplish?

What happens if you add `onError` handler?

Comment: using `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());` should handle the network error, what other errors are you getting?

Comment: @ZacharySweigart - how would using different Schedulers help, OP is already using their own custom schedulers? What is this method doing `sendUserInfo` - post code. By the way `doOnNext` is a "side effect" operator, you should handle responses in subscriber (`onNext`), long with propagated errors in (`onError`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [RxJava2 Adapter](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2), it will save you a lot!

**Step 1:** Retrofit client setup

```
   private Retrofit getRetrofitClient() {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()) //option 1
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.newThread())) //option 2
                .build();
    }
```

**Step 2:** APIService interface (Example)

```
@GET("endpoint")
Single<ResponseModel> fetch();
```

**Step 3:** Usage

```
  Single<ResponseModel> fetch() {
        return getRetrofitClient()
                    .create(APIService.class)
                    .fetch();
    }
```

- Any non-2xx HTTP response will be wrapped in `HttpException` from which you can extract the status code, the status message and the full HTTP response.
- Any connection errors will be wrapped in `IOException`

And that is all you need to do to wrap your network call in any RxJava stream.